# Upgrading the SDK to a newer SDK

Tags: android

I have an app running on android 2.1 and I would like to update it to android 3.2 as I do not have anyone using that version. How do I go about doing that? I changed the min sdk in manifest but I was wondering about the JAR file. Do I download the jar for that version. Do I keep the old jar. 
Thanks
Prerna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter what the Android version is of the jar file. That is only what target the application compiles with. If you want to change that, click on your project, File -> Properties -> Android and check the desired project build target (i.e. 3.2) and Apply.